# Laravel form request with geocoder

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, laravel-5, request

I have form in my view that is made of checkboxes, some textfields and selects.

On the same page I have googlemap geocoder. The location lat&lng is saved in variables in javascript.

[image: screenshoot of webpage form]

```
function geocodeAddress(geokodiranje, resultsMap) {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var location = {};
    geokodiranje.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            location.lattitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            location.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            lat = location.lattitude;  //THIS IS MY LAT
            lng = location.longitude; //THIS IS MY LNG 
        } else {
            alert('Geocode failed for reason: ' + status);
        }

    });

}
```

And in my controller I have POST function to save form in database.

```
$input = Request::all();
Blogpost::create($input);
return redirect('other');
```

In my DB I have columns for lat and lng and I want to add variables and the problem is that I can't add this 2 variables into $input variable in my controller. Help me please! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add 2 hidden field lat and lon in your form like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="lat" class="lat" />
<input type="hidden" name="lon" class="lon" />
```

And set value in js code like this way :

```
function geocodeAddress(geokodiranje, resultsMap) {
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
var location = {};
geokodiranje.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        location.lattitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        location.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: resultsMap,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        lat = location.lattitude;  //THIS IS MY LAT
        lng = location.longitude; //THIS IS MY LNG 
        $('.lat').val(lat);
        $('.lon').val(lng);
    } else {
        alert('Geocode failed for reason: ' + status);
    }

});
```

}